# POST Request Basic Authorization - Not Working for Battle.net API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, post, axios, postman

I have formatted an axios post request as follows:

```
    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://us.battle.net/oauth/token',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': 'Basic '+process.env.BATTLENET_CLIENT+':'+process.env.BATTLENET_SECRET, 
            ...data.getHeaders()
        },
        data : data
    };
```

This is getting rejected with a 401. However, when I generate the code snippet for this out of Postman, which functions, it is the same, except the Authorization is a seemingly random string that was generated:

```
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://us.battle.net/oauth/token',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Basic reallyRandomLongStringIsNotClientIDAndSecretKey=', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};
```

Plugging this into my code made it work. I'm curious if there is something I'm missing when coding Basic Auth credentials, as it seems Postman has converted/encrypted it into something I can not figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to encode the string with username and password/secret to Base64 like this:

```js
const encodedAuthorization = Buffer.from(`${process.env.BATTLENET_CLIENT}:${process.env.BATTLENET_SECRET}`).toString('base64')
 var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://us.battle.net/oauth/token',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedAuthorization}`, 
            ...data.getHeaders()
        },
        data : data
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed that the authorization needed to be encoded to Base64. This now works!

Answer (score 0):

The [Basic-Auth-Authentication-Scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617) functions as follows:

1. The client provides credentials in the form of a "username" and a "password".
2. Username and password are concatenated with a colon: "username:password"
3. The concatenated string is encoded in base64
4. The header value is then the base64-encoded string prefixed with "Basic "

Below you can see a javascript implementation:

```js
const userName = "username"
const password = "password"

const authenticationHeader = "Basic " + btoa(`${userName}:${password}`)
```